# What section of the 2016 Berserk anime is covered by the 3rd movie, The Advent?

Tags: berserk

I want to know what episodes of the anime that the movie covers. Take
movies 1 and 2 which cover episodes 1-20.

I've heard the third movie covers episodes 21-25 and X episodes of the 2016 anime. And so I want to know what those X episodes are.

I'm not asking for anything plot-wise, I just want to know how much of the 2016 anime it covers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've heard the third movie covers episodes 21-25 and X episodes of the 2016 anime.

Actually, no, the third movie doesn't cover any episodes of the 2016 anime.

The 3-part movie covers the whole *Golden Age* arc (volume 3-14), while the 2016 anime **omits the whole *Golden Age* arc** and starts/continues from *Conviction* arc (volume 14).

> The final part of the movie goes beyond episode 25 of the original anime. My question is what is covered there?

The original anime covers the *Black Swordsman* arc (volume 1-3) until **just before the end of *Golden Age* arc** (volume 3-**13**). As mentioned before, the movie covers until volume 14. Thus, the final part of the movie covers the end of *Golden Age* arc (volume 14), which is not adapted anywhere else (movie exclusive).

---

For more information on *Berserk* adaptation's storyline, you can refer to [How much of the Berserk storyline do the anime and OVA cover?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7335/how-much-of-the-berserk-storyline-do-the-anime-and-ova-cover)?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can remember, the new anime doesn't cover anything the movies covered and vice-versa (unless flashbacks and recap episodes). I think you're thinking of the original show and the movies overlapping.

Comment: The final part of the movie goes beyond episode 25 of the original anime. My question is what is covered there.